# Word for words expressing utterances

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for the sort of words that sometimes precede dialogue or quotations, like *say*, *ask*, *write*, *answer*, *cry,* and *reply*?

Comment: I think it's usually called a "tag", but someone might correct me. I'm pretty sure there is a word for it, at any rate.

Comment: Are you speaking of verbs, or are you talking about, say, interjections? If the latter, I have to say that _say_ is the only interjection in the list; all the rest are verbs of speech with special grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are called "dialogue tags." Have a look here:
https://www.visualthesaurus.com/wordlists/9457

Comment: Perfect. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well that is my first answer on this site. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Latin grammars the term verba dicendi (verbs of saying) is used in the meaning of all verbs that can be used before direct or indirect speech.

Comment: And Cobuild, I think it is, distinguishes _quote verbs_ or _quotative verbs_ from _reporting verbs_.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble finding any definitive sources that back me up here, and I am aware that Wikipedia is not an academically-acceptable source, but its page on [Dialogue in Writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogue_in_writing) seems to indicate they are called *identifiers* (because they identify the person who is currently speaking in a dialogue).

[TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SaidBookism) identifies the use of words other than 'said' as a 'Said-Bookism', but that's more referring to the concept of using those words than a name for the words themselves. I'm afraid that's all the information I have at present.

Comment: "Said-bookism" is a great term for the bad-writing examples like shriek, exclaim, and lament--thanks for a new term! But the word I'm looking for would be more general and descriptive, less judgmental.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help in that regard - you're welcome.